# JSP parent/child param manipulation

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a parent jsp file that includes two child jsp's. I have a variable defined in the parent file like so:

```
<c:set var="test" value="N" />
```

which I then pass into two child jsp files:

```
<div id="div_data_1" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page1.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="controlFlag" value="${test}"/>
    </jsp:include>
</div>

<div id="div_data_2" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page2.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="controlFlag" value="${test}"/>
    </jsp:include>
</div>
```

In my page1.jsp file I then store the value in a hidden div:

```
<div id="cashAuditFlag" style="display: none;">${param.cashAuditFlag}</div>
```

I then have a button in page1.jsp that, when clicked, I want it to change the value of the parent variable `${test}` to `"Y"`. This in turn would then change the value of `${test}` in page2.jsp which would cause a change in page2.jsp.

I basically want to have a child jsp communicate an update to another child jsp, both of which belong to the same parent.

A - Is this the best way of doing this process?

B - How can I have a child jsp update the parent jsp variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To understand this, you need to understand scopes.** Think of a scope as a bucket that variables go into when they are defined. Some code only has access to some of those buckets.

Request scoped variables are available in any part of the code that knows about the http request. There is only one request scope per HTTP request to your webapp. In your example, the parent file, page1.jsp, and page2.jsp all have access to that request scope. For example, if you did this in your parent JSP page:

```
<c:set var="test" value="N" scope="request" />
```

...it would put the "test" variable into the request scope bucket with a value of N.

Then, if you want to view or modify this value in either page1.jsp or page2.jsp, you don't even need to have a jsp:param element in your jsp:include, so you can just do this:

```
<div id="div_data_1" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page1.jsp"/>
</div>

<div id="div_data_2" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page2.jsp"/>
</div>
```

So, if you want to display this in either child page, you can simply use Expression Language and tell it to look in the requestScope for the variable named "test" by using the requestScope object:

```
<p>The Test Variable is: ${requestScope.test}</p>
```

Similarly, if you wanted to modify this variable in either childPage, you can simply do another c:set statement:

```
    <c:set var="test" value="Y" scope="request" />
```

Now, if you print out the value of ${requestScope.test} in any page, it will be Y.

In your example, when you used the c:set statement without scope="request", you created a variable in that jsp page's "page scope", meaning you could only access that variable in the jsp code you wrote in your parent jsp page.

**Now, as to whether this is the best way to do this...**

You say you have a button in page1.jsp that, when clicked, should change the test variable to Y and cause some display change in page2.jsp. Here's the flow of what would need to happen:

1. User vists your JSP page at some url, like "mywebapp/testPage.jsp"
2. The page renders. The initial c:set statement runs which sets the "test" var to a value of "N".
3. The user clicks the button, which causes the browser to send a new request but adds a request parameter, resulting in a request of something like "mywebapp/testPage.jsp?buttonClicked=1"
4. All your JSP pages render again (keep in mind JSP does not do things "dynamically" i.e. without a browser refresh - when you click a button, the browser sends a new HTTP request to the webserver and your JSP is rendered again).
5. At the top of your parent JSP, you need logic that checks whether the buttonClicked request parameter is present. If so, it sets the value of test to "Y" instead of "N".

So, to explain: in order to have the page render differently based on whether the button was just clicked, you would need to have your button pass a request parameter when it is clicked, and you would need to have your JSP look at the new request to find that request parameter (to see the value that was submitted when the button was clicked). If you don't have your code check that, then, every time your page loads, your parent JSP page will just keep re-setting the test variable to N because your initial c:set value="N" statement will always run when the JSP renders.

So, if you want something like the case you described, you'd have to do something like this in your parent JSP page:

```
<c:set var="test" value="N" scope="request"/>
<!-- Here's the check for whether the request parameter is present -->
<c:if test="${not empty param.buttonClicked}">
    <c:set var="test" value="Y" scope="request"/>
</c:if>

<div id="div_data_1" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page1.jsp"/>
</div>

<div id="div_data_2" style="display:none;">
    <jsp:include page="page2.jsp"/>
</div>
```

...then in page1.jsp, where you have the button, you would do something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="buttonClicked" value="1" />
```

That way, when the button is clicked, it will refresh the page and add a new request parameter called buttonClicked with a value of "1". In the parent JSP, it will see that this request parameter is present (with "not empty param.buttonClicked") and it will set the value of the test variable to "Y", overwriting the previous assignment of "N".

Then in your page2.jsp, you can access the value of test using ${requestScope.test} at any point on your page.